# How to configure Zend Framework 2 each module to each Hostname?

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2

I have 2 domain and I want to configure such a way that each module route to my domain.

e.g.

```
 1. domain1 module = domain1.ashwin.com
 2. domain2 module = domain2.ashwin.com
```

I have following code:

> module.config.php for domain1 module

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Hostname',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => 'domain1.ashwin.com',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Domain1\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'home' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Domain1\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

> module.config.php for domain2 module

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'domain2' => array(
                'type' => 'Hostname',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => 'domain2.ashwin.com',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Domain2\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'home' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Domain2\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your code, you have declared the route 'home' 3 times. Keep in mind that the routes are actually merged together to big array when Zend 
starts up you modules.

if we take your module.config.php for domain1 as an example
you should do something like this

```
'routes' => array(
    'domain1' => array(
        'type' => 'Hostname',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => 'domain1.ashwin.com',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'Domain1\Controller\Index',
                'action'     => 'index',
            ),
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(
            'default' => array(
                'type'    => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Domain1\Controller',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```